# Share css across multiple sites in Firebase

Tags: css, firebase, firebase-hosting

I made a webgl product configurator web app. I want each app act like a small site.
I want to be able to change my css at once and deploy it to all sites.

This is my firebase.json, and my css is in de public folder.

```
{
"hosting": [
    {
        "target": "hosting-site-1",
        "public": "public/folder-1",
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
    },
    {
        "target": "hosting-site-2",
        "public": "public/folder-2",
        "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Please elaborate your question. And please take a look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.